# How to fix backup command?

Tags: files-and-directories

The following old code, from "Dr Bob" and Selwyn Hollis with a minor modification by me, produces a palette that allows one to create successive backups to the input notebook.

But the code breaks in case one changes global option `Notebook Options`Window Properties`WindowTitle` to `"FullFileName"`. How can it be fixed?

```
CreatePalette[
  {Button["Bare Bones Backup", 
     Module[{filename, thisnb = InputNotebook[],
       savedir = ToFileName[{"~/Backup", "Mathematica BareBones Backups"}]},
       If[thisnb =!= $Failed,
          If[! DirectoryQ[savedir], CreateDirectory[savedir]];
       filename = 
        StringJoin[StringReplace[(WindowTitle /. AbsoluteOptions[thisnb]), 
           s_ ~~ ".nb" -> s], "_", 
           StringJoin[ToString /@ Round /@ Rest[Date[]]], ".nb"];
      Export[ToFileName[savedir, filename], 
        DeleteCases[NotebookGet[thisnb], Cell[_, "Output", ___],    
           Infinity]]]]]}, 
        Saveable -> True]
```

Comment: @ilian: Works perfectly! Make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [`FileBaseName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileBaseName.html), which will strip both the directory specification and the `.nb` extension, e.g.

```
filename = StringJoin[FileBaseName[WindowTitle /. AbsoluteOptions[thisnb]], "_", 
                        ToString /@ Round /@ Rest[Date[]]], ".nb"];
```